# Circular reference - break on single reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection, weak-references, circular-reference

**TL;DR** Is there any way to create a weak reference that will call a callback upon having 1 strong reference left instead of 0?

---

For those who think it's an X Y problem, here's the long explanation:

I have quite a challenging issue that I'm trying to solve with my code.

Suppose we have an instance of some class Foo, and a different class Bar which references the instance as it uses it:

```
class Foo:  # Can be anything
    pass

class Bar:
    """I must hold the instance in order to do stuff"""
    def __init__(self, inst):
        self.inst = inst

foo_to_bar = {}
def get_bar(foo):
    """Creates Bar if one doesn't exist"""
    return foo_to_bar.setdefault(foo, Bar(foo))

# We can either have
bar = get_foobar(Foo())
# Bar must hold a strong reference to foo

# Or
foo = Foo()
bar = get_foobar(foo)
bar2 = get_foobar(foo)  # Same Bar
del bar
del bar2
bar3 = get_foobar(foo)  # Same Bar
# In this case, as long as foo exists, we want the same bar to show up,
# therefore, foo must in some way hold a strong reference back to bar
```

Now here's the tricky part: You can solve this issue using a circular reference, where `foo` references `bar` and `bar` references `foo`, but hey, what's the fun part in that? It will take longer to clean up, will not work in case Foo defines `__slots__` and generally will be a poor solution.

Is there any way, I can create a `foo_to_bar` mapping that cleans upon a **single** reference to both `foo` and `bar`? In essence:

```
import weakref
foo_to_bar = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
# If bar is referenced only once (as the dict value) and foo is
# referenced only once (from bar.inst) their mapping will be cleared out
```

This way it can work perfectly as having `foo` outside the function makes sure `bar` is still there (I might require `__slots__` on `Foo` to support `__weakref__`) and having `bar` outside the function results in `foo` still being there (because of the strong reference in `Bar`).

`WeakKeyDictionary` does not work beacuse `{weakref.ref(inst): bar.inst}` will cause circular reference.

Alternatively, is there any way to hook into the reference counting mechanism (in order to clean when both objects get to 1 reference each) without incurring significant overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking this. You don't need to track if there is just one reference  left. Your mistake is to create a circular reference in the first place.

Store `_BarInner` objects in your cache, that have *no reference to `Foo` instances*. Upon access to the mapping, return a lightweight `Bar` instance that contains both the `_BarInner` and `Foo` references:

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
from collections.abc import Mapping


class Foo:
    pass


class Bar:
    """I must hold the instance in order to do stuff"""
    def __init__(self, inst, inner):
        self._inst = inst
        self._inner = inner

    # Access to interesting stuff is proxied on to the inner object,
    # with the instance information included *as needed*.
    @property
    def spam(self):
        self.inner.spam(self.inst)


class _BarInner:
    """The actual data you want to cache"""
    def spam(self, instance):
        # do something with instance, but *do not store any references to that
        # object on self*.


class BarMapping(Mapping):
    def __init__(self):
        self._mapping = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __getitem__(self, inst):
        inner = self._mapping.get(inst)
        if inner is None:
            inner = self._mapping[inst] = _BarInner()
        return Bar(inst, inner)
```

Translating this to the [`bdict` project](https://github.com/bharel/bdict/blob/master/bdict/__init__.py) linked in the comments, you can simplify things drastically:

- Don't worry about lack of support for weak references in projects. Document that your project will only support per-instance data on types that have a `__weakref__` attribute. That's enough.
- Don't distinguish between slots and no-slots types. Always store per-instance data away from the instances. This lets you simplify your code.
- The same goes for the 'strong' and 'autocache' flags. The flyweight should always keep a strong reference. Per-instance data should always be stored.
- Use a single class for the descriptor return value. The `ClassBoundDict` type is all you need. Store the `instance` and `owner` data passed to `__get__` in that object, and vary behaviour in `__setitem__` accordingly.
- Look at [`collections.ChainMap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to encapsulate access to the class and instance mappings for read access.

Comment: I guess I tried optimizing too much and turned the code a little ugly. While I did know `ChainMap` beforehand, I haven't thought of always accessing the original `BDict`. It causes a little bit of overhead but creates a clean codebase. Thanks mate, you're a great teacher.